# What does E6A mean In fortran code

Tags: vb.net, fortran

I'm trying to do some interesting orbit mechanics, I've found some related code in Fortan and I'm going through line by line moving it to Visual Basic. I can't understand what this is though:

```
IF(ABS(EPW-TEMP2) .LE. E6A) GO TO 140
```

It's not a variable. I figure E6 might be 10^6 but what's the 'A' mean?

Thanks!

Comment: A bit more context is necessary. Fortran won't let `E6A` sit by itself on a line, what is the rest of the line say? Maybe include a line or two before and after for even more context.

Comment: The full line says: IF(ABS(EPW-TEMP2) .LE. E6A) GO TO 140. EPW is a variable as is temp2. I believe .LE. is less than or equal to (from context).

Comment: From the context I'm guessing it means 10^(-6). But this seems like odd syntax to represent this.

Comment: It does not mean 1e-6 (though it probably is a tolerance). Assuming that the original coder was intelligent, `E6A` must be defined somewhere. Are there common blocks in the code?

Comment: Does the `You can be a great Fortran programmer in any language` adage apply here? Is the VB code going to be filled with Fortran gems like this one?

Comment: Just for reference, which fortran IDE/compiler did this come form?

Comment: And where does the Fortran source come from? [as Kyle said, E6A is just a variable (or maybe a constant), and it must be defined somewhere]

Comment: Even if you can't find declaration, `E6A` can still be treated as a variable name.  From the appearance of `GO TO` statement I would assume this code does not have `implicit none` and `E6A` would just be another variable that become implicitly declared and used before assigned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I google that line of code, I end up with some "[Spacetrack Report No.3](https://celestrak.org/NORAD/documentation/spacetrk.pdf)" with the fortran code listing. And `E6A` is defined as `1.E-6` in the routine `DRIVER` (Page. 73)

```
DATA DE2RA,E6A,PI,PIO2,QO,SO,TOTHRD,TWOPI,X3PIO2,XJ2,XJ3,
1 XJ4,XKE,XKMPER,XMNPDA,AE/.174532925E-1,1.E-6,
2 3.14159265,1.57079633,120.0,78.0,.66666667,
4 6.2831853,4.71238898,1.082616E-3,-.253881E-5,
5 -1.65597E-6,.743669161E-1,6378.135,1440.,1.
```

I see this code has already been converted to Java and C, perhaps you should use those as reference.